# Unable to view images in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am unable to view images on my webserver in `php` and I keep getting `server 500` error.

I believe that it is this line of code `echo "<img src='$row["sourchPath"]'>"`:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row){
        echo $row["sourchPath"]; // this works
        echo "<img src='$row["sourchPath"]'>";
    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

My file directory is like `images/football.jpg`

Comment: *"and I keep getting server 500 error."* - look at your logs.

Comment: Do you see - even code highlightning shows you error.

Comment: then: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll *see* them. "parse error".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this line:

```
echo "<img src='$row["sourchPath"]'>";  // syntax error
```

It should be,

```
echo "<img src='" . $row["sourchPath"] . "' />";
```

Comment: IT WORKS MAN! I LOVE YOU (NO HOMO)!!!! GENIUS. Could you explain why I was getting the error?

Comment: @ChrisFezdesovoit See the formation of double quotes i.e where it's starting and ending, you'll see the syntax error.

Comment: ...it's called "concatenation" @ChrisFezdesovoit ;-) not doing that, causes a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

You may use
       `echo "<img src='" . $row["sourchPath"] . "'>";` 
in place of your code.

It will work